# PHP - Preg replace on URLS from string failure

Tags: php, url, replace, hyperlink

This is my function:

```
    function makeClickableLinks($s) {
  return preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $s);
}


$description = $_POST['description'];

echo makeClickableLinks($description);
```

$_POST['description'] is a form textarea that will be inserted later into a MySQL table.

I want to allow users to create links within this input field. When I use this function, user inputted data that looks like this:

```
Whats up guys. Here's my website! Please check it out!!
<a href="google.com">hi</a>
```

Is now a clickable link, but links to:

```
http://(myurl).com/google.com
```

It thinks the link is a subdirectory. Any ideas? THankS!

Comment: You must prefix the link with http:// (or https://, or anything else) otherwise it is considered a relative link and appended to the currently viewed URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to organize something like replacing the references in the user's records, so that they referred to your site. Tray this regexp:

```
<?php
$str = "Whats up guys. Here's my website! Please check it out!!
<a href='google.com'>hi</a> and something:)";

echo preg_replace("/(<a[^<]* href=['\"])(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?([^\"]*?)(['\"][^<]*>)/is", "$1mysite.com/$3$4", $str);
```

Comment: Dude thank you this worked after a little tweaking. Here's what I use: echo preg_replace("/(<a[^<]* href=['\"])(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?([^\"]*?)(['\"][^<]*>)/is", "$1http:///$3$4", $str)

Answer (score 0):

This is relative link problem. in your function makeClickableLinks($s), you have check whether link starts with http or https if not append http:// with it. find example below.

```
function makeClickableLinks($s) {
    $link = ( strpos($s, 'http://') === 0 || strpos($s, 'https://') === 0) ? '' : 'http://'.$s;
    return $link;
}
```

Comment: @user1093634 I have updated my answer, can you try that let me know?

Comment: Hi and thank you. Your script does not work. It produces links as such: <a href="www.google.com">click</a> becomes http://click